# If let not still giving "Optional must be unwrapped" error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Here is my struct:

```
struct EditableCircleImage: View {

    @State private var image: Image?
    @State private var inputImage: UIImage?
    @State private var animatedImage: AnimatedImage?

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
        ...
        }
            
    }
    func loadImage() {
        guard let img = inputImage else {
            return
        }
        animatedImage = AnimatedImage(data: img.jpegData(compressionQuality: .infinity))
    }
}
```

My `animatedImage` assignment in `loadImage()` is giving the following error:

```
Value of optional type 'Data?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Data'
```

even though `img` is guaranteed to not be `null` as it is created from a `guard let`.

I also tested `if let inputImage = inputImage` and it gives the same error.

Any idea why?

Comment: `img` is not an optional, but `img.jpegData` is: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624115-jpegdata. Note that the compiler complains about `Data?`, not about `UIImage?`

Comment: `func jpegData(compressionQuality: CGFloat) -> Data?`. It's the result which is optional. guard let data = img.jpegData(compressionQuality: .infinity) else { return }; animatedImage = AnimatedImage (data: data)`

Comment: Ah that makes sense .. thanks. Changing to `guard let img = inputImage?.jpegData(compressionQuality: .infinity) else` fixes the problem..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned into documents for [jpegData(compressionQuality:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/1624115-jpegdata)

**Declaration**

```
func jpegData(compressionQuality: CGFloat) -> Data?
```

**Return Value**

> A data object containing the JPEG data, or nil if there was a problem
> generating the data. This function may return nil if the image has no
> data or if the underlying CGImageRef contains data in an unsupported
> bitmap format.

So basically it's not `img` object which is causing this error. but it's return value from `jpegData` property of `UIImage`.

You can use `guard let` or `if let` to get the explicit value from `jpegData` property.